# Save VF form in edit mode without refreshing

Tags: ajax, salesforce, visualforce, apex, salesforce-service-cloud

We are developing VF pages that will ultimately be integrated into the service console.
One of the requirements is that the VF pages always be in edit mode, and on clicking the save button (or alternatively pressing ctrl+s), the fields should be saved without refreshing the page or the form. Edit mode is achieved using

> `<apex:pageBlock title="Edit Case" mode="edit">`

Is it possible to implement the save functionality while still using the standard controller save method since it always returns a page reference?
If not, what would be the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to leverage QuickSave while specifying the `rerender` attribute to skip the page redirect/refresh:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!quicksave}" value="Save" rerender="null" />
```

If you want to rerender a specific portion of the page after the save has occured, replace `null` with the appropriate VF component ID.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had tried earlier with rerender="none" but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Would using the quicksave action on the Standard Controller be an option?

For example:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!quicksave}" value="Save" />
```

In this way, the save would still occur but there would be no redirect.

Comment: I tried that, but it still refreshes the page... The only difference is that it does not redirect you to some other page.

Comment: Ah yes, my apologies, I seem to have missed the requirement that it doesn't refresh in your original question.